# Integrating office 365 to keycloak

Tags: office365, keycloak

I want to do integration between the office 365 and keycloak.

For example: If i entered my office 365 credentials in keycloak authentication form it should be validate and return back the valid access token to authenticate the application url.

Is the any way to integrate office 365 to keycloak?

Thanks in advance.